# sort javascript populated select list by alphabetical order

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to sort my javascript popuplated select list and ive searched through all the other posts on this site but i cant get it to work...

here is my javascript that auto populates the select list from an data in an SQL db:

```
for (clientKey in clientProjectsHash) {
            //alert("client:" + clientKey + ", name: " + clientProjectsHash[clientKey].name);
            clientSelect.options[clientSelect.options.length] = new Option(clientProjectsHash[clientKey].name, clientKey);

            if(selectedClientId == undefined || selectedClientId == 0) {
                if(clientKey > 0) {
                    selectedClientId=clientKey;
                }
            }
```

ive tried to add:
`clientProjectsHash.sort();` to the top but it doesn't work... anyone help is appreciated!

this is my other function to get the first client ID from database:

```
function getInitialClient() {
    for (clientKey in clientProjectsHash) {
        if(clientKey > 0) {
            return clientKey;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here we go.

You want to sort an object's enumerable keys by their values.

- You can use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get the enumerable properties of an object.
- Then, you can use [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to convert each key, to its value in the object.

(That link has a shim for older browsers in both of those)

- Then you can call the normal [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function on them.

**Example**

Let's say your object is something like

```
var obj = {
    "a":"Hello",
    "b":"World",
    "c":"AAAA",
    "d":"ZZZZ",    
};

var a = Object.keys(obj).map(function(elem){ // Get the keys, and map them
    return obj[elem];     // to their value
}).sort(); // then sort
```

#### [Here is a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tVHcY/)

#### Your case:

In your case, this would be something like

```
var sortedValues = Object.keys(clientProjectsHash).map(function(elem){ // Get the keys, and map them
        return clientProjectsHash[elem];     // to their value
    }).sort();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
var list = [];
for(key in clientProjectsHash)
    list.push(key);
list.sort();
for(var i=0; i<list.length; i++)
{
   clientSelect.options[clientSelect.options.length] = new Option(clientProjectsHash[list[i]].name, clientKey);

        if(selectedClientId == undefined || selectedClientId == 0) {
            if(clientKey > 0) {
                selectedClientId=clientKey;
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: is `clientProjectsHash` an `array` or an `object`?

Comment: never mind, form your code it's an `object`. Objects don't have a `.sort()` method. that's the problem. Gimme one sec, and I'll push a work around where you can pull all the keys into an array, sort the array and then go through them after they're sorted.

Comment: Just for future reference `Array.sort()` returns the new array *and* modifies the original. See what `var a = ['b','c','a']; a.sort(); console.log(a);` gives.

Comment: thanks, @pebbl I was under the impression it left the original array untouched.

Comment: @JasonNichols no worries, it's one of those annoying functions that doesn't do what you expect :)

Comment: this is a great solution but it still did not put my list in alphabetical order... pretty much just ordered ID from 10,11,12, and so on... but ID #10 is Elections so it didnt choose the ID that starts with letter A